# Submit a form without using submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using a form to submit the data to get the records from the database.
In the form I am using the two select tag options.

So after selecting the options the form should submit **without using the submit button**.
I am waiting for the response to submit the form after selecting the inputs without using the submit button(or any button) it should submit automatically.

Comment: How do you tell if the form is filled completely or still need work?\

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the form supposed to be submitted on any selection? Or just on both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a function to check everything you want has been set, and then if it has, submit the form:

```
function submitIfFormComplete()
{
  // Check the select has something selected
  if (document.getElementById('selectOne').selectedIndex > 0)
  {
      document.getElementById('formID').submit();
  }
}
```

Then on your select, bind the *onchange* event to run the function.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JE6AM/

```
Select your car make:
<select id='sel1' name='selectCar' onchange="checkAndSubmit()">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<br/><br/>
Select your gender:
<select id='sel2' name='selectGender' onchange="checkAndSubmit()">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
  <option value="Male">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Female">Saab</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkAndSubmit()
{
  if (document.getElementById('sel1').selectedIndex > 0
     && document.getElementById('sel2').selectedIndex > 0)
  {
      //document.getElementById('formID').submit();
      alert('both have been selected!');
  }
}
```

I've replaced the submit with an alert() to show you how the code triggers.

Edit: You can use `$_REQUEST['selectCar']` to access the value.

Comment: @SLC..Thank you..this is working..but I have to retreiv the values i have selected..how can I do that?..If I use submit button,I can retrev the values using $_REQUEST['name']..But here how can retreiv the values I have selected?..

Comment: @SLC..May I know how can I get the values I have selected in both the selct options?

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing with $_REQUEST, just ensure that your `<select>` has a `name` property. I've edited my answer to put this `name` property in.

Answer (score 4):

Every form has a `submit()` function.

```
<form name="myForm">
...
</form>
```

can be submitted with

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

Comment: This is true. @bhai you can use javascript on change function for you dropdowns and submit the form using this answer code.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has been used to easily to submit the form.

```
<form id="test">
<select name="select1" id="select1">

</select>
</form>

$('#select1').change(function() {
    $("#test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="submit.php" id="submitform" method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="nm"> <br>
Age:<input type="number" name="age">
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('submitform').submit()">submit</a>
```

Comment: You should briefly explain why your answer will work